# Grails:Try to validate just part of properties of command object but get a exception

Tags: grails

According to official docs I can pass a list of properties as a parameter to `validate()`.
But when I try to call `validate()` on a command object like this:

```
groupCmd.validate(['startDate'])
```

I get a exception like following:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: GroupCommand.validate() is     
applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[startDate]]
```

Does this mean only when using `validate()` on a domain class instance, you can pass a list of properties to be validated, but not on a command object?

And is there some ways to just validate some of properties of a command object?

And I use grails 1.3.7

Best Regards
Thanks to Mualig for formatting my article

Comment: Just to make sure, validate() without the list works? Did you tried in the latest version of Grails?